# PHP module is not being installed into /etc/apache2/mods-available

Tags: raspbian, web-server, php, apache-httpd

I'm trying to serve a website running Apache2 alongside PHP on my Raspberry Pi 1.3.

I have already installed Apache with `sudo apt install apache2 -y` followed by `sudo apt install php libapache2-mod-php -y`. The RootDocument is pointing to index.php.

However, PHP is not loading. When I try to lookup the module inside /etc/apache2/mods-available, the PHP module itself is nowhere to be found. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

`libapache2-mod-php` is a virtual package provided by `libapache2-mod-php7.3` in Buster and `libapache2-mod-php7.0` in Stretch. Check if you have the correct package installed. If not, you should find out why (perhaps you need to run `sudo apt-get -f install`). As a last resort, you can install the correct package manually.

Answer (score 0):

Run the Apache module enable software.

From memory

`sudo a2enmod`